# I want an MS TOC entry which is different from the text it points to - like an Epigram - I want the word 'Epigram' not the actual Epigram

Tags: ms-word, tableofcontents

I want an entry in my TOC (that was created with Headings 1, 2 & 3) that is not the same as the text it points to. So I want to have the word 'Epigram' in the TOC but I want some text like; 'For Joey and Suzy, thanks for all the help' to appear on the page as the 'target' for the 'Epigram' entry in the TOC.

Hope that is clear ! Thanks for any help, much appreciated.

Have only tried googling this but difficult to describe in a 'searchy' way.

Comment: In which case you want something that is not capable of inclusion in a Table of Contents. In any event, this is not a programming question and, as such, is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: If you re-post your question on superuser.com I will try to answer it.

Comment: Ok Guys, sorry made the mistake, apologies. I will post the question on superuser.com as suggested - thanks for the pointers.